# Flash object not loading in Safari

Tags: safari, flash, show-hide

I've built a form, and next to my form element I've placed a flash object.  When the page is loaded, the form is display: block, and the flash object is display: none.

The layout looks something like (the img is there so that if the user doesn't have flash, the gif animation will play instead):

```
<form id="form"></form>
<div id="upload-anim-div">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      data="<?= PAL_STATIC_HOST ?>/music/introducing/flash/upload_animation.swf"
      width="626"
      height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="<?= PAL_STATIC_HOST ?>/music/introducing/flash/upload_animation.swf"/>
    <img src="<?= PAL_STATIC_HOST ?>/music/introducing/img/Anim-placeholder.gif" alt="upload animation (gif)"/>
  </object>
</div>
```

When I submit my form, which is just to upload a file, I hide the form and display my animation div as follows in javascript:

```
$('#form').hide();
$('#upload-anim-div').show();
```

This works great in all browsers except Safari, where a big white space appears.  Right clicking this white space simply gives me the following menu:

```
Flash movie not loaded... _not clickable_
About Adobe Flash Player 10.5.blah...
```

Why is the movie not loaded/loading?!  If I simply display the movie when the document first loads (by removing the javascript line that initially hides it) it loads and displays fine!  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

---EDIT---

I've now tried using swfobject, but get exactly the same problem.  I used this kind of code in my javascript to embed my swf with javascript after displaying the upload-anim-div:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "upload-anim-div", "626", "600", "10");
```

Anyone have any further ideas?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem, except that I'm not using any hidden containers. I'm using exactly the same code that comes from the swfobject generator [with the proper names and ids] and it works in every browser except for safari. I'm currently working with safari 5.0.4 in a mac. I'm sure this must be a newbie mistake but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Safari tries to shave the page load time by not rendering Flash in a hidden div.  How are you putting the Flash into the div, is it just an object tag, or are you using something like swfobject?  If you're using swfobject you could write the Flash to the div when you reveal it.

Comment: yup just an object tag.  I know very little flash  so I'm afraid I don't know how I'd go about writing 'the Flash to the div when you reveal it'..

Comment: Look at Rob's link above. swfobject is very easy to use, and you can always post here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to embed your Flash content with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/):

Comment: thansks for the link.  Do you not think think there's any simpler way of getting this done?  It currently works in every single other browser!

Comment: :) Give it a go, you will like it.

Comment: so can you tell me what I'd need to change in my HTML markup other than add 'include swfobject.js' to get this to work..?

Comment: Dude, on the website there are examples and documentation, check them out.

Comment: having implemented swfobject to embed the flash once I show the div I get exactly the same problem..

Comment: What happens if you don't hide your flash containing div at start? Does it appear or still doesn't shop up in Safari?

Comment: if I don't hide the div, the animation plays (this applies using both techniques - object and swfobject).  It seems to _only_ and _always_ be a problem when a hide the div and then show it later.

Comment: So have you tried making your call to swfobject as you reveal the hidden div?  Safari might not like inserting Flash content into a hidden container.